# How to convert shipping methods to dropdown in Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce, webhooks

Hey in Woocommerce im trying to convert the shipping methods radio buttons to  a dropdown list. this is the list html

```
<ul id="shipping_method">
                                <li>
                    <input type="radio" name="shipping_method[0]" data-index="0" id="shipping_method_0_flat_rate1" value="flat_rate:1" class="shipping_method">
                            <label for="shipping_method_0_flat_rate1">רעננה: <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">₪</span>16</span></label>                 </li>
                                <li>
                    <input type="radio" name="shipping_method[0]" data-index="0" id="shipping_method_0_flat_rate7" value="flat_rate:7" class="shipping_method" checked="checked">
                            <label for="shipping_method_0_flat_rate7">נתניה: <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">₪</span>30</span></label>                 </li>
                                <li>
                    <input type="radio" name="shipping_method[0]" data-index="0" id="shipping_method_0_flat_rate8" value="flat_rate:8" class="shipping_method">
                            <label for="shipping_method_0_flat_rate8">חדרה: <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">₪</span>45</span></label>                  </li>
                                <li>
                    <input type="radio" name="shipping_method[0]" data-index="0" id="shipping_method_0_free_shipping3" value="free_shipping:3" class="shipping_method">
                            <label for="shipping_method_0_free_shipping3">איסוף עצמי חינם</label>                   </li>
                        </ul>
```

is there any hook i can use?
any quick trick ?

Answer (score 0):

Try the WooCommerce Shipping Method Display Style plug-in (tested on WordPress v4.9.8 + WooCommerce v3.4.7):

https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-shipping-display-mode/